# Set Multiple views/layouts in the parent layout equally

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How do I set multiple layouts on the same view so that they both share the space equally?

The following url has the image for my requirement:

[How to set two different layouts for one view using constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934316/how-to-set-two-different-layouts-for-one-view-using-constraints)

Each of the RelativeLayouts are to be laid one over the other.
Please suggest the modificiation needed for my current xml for this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ScrollAct" >

    <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/rlExtendBar;"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?"> 
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/rel_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?">

    </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you need to put the two children inside one parent. You need to use the attribute

> android:layout_weight="1"

to do what you want.

So, if you want the to divide the screen vertically, you have to do something like that :

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <!-- Here, the content-->

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <!-- Here, the content-->

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And to divide horizontally :

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <!-- Here, the content-->

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <!-- Here, the content-->

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that android:layout_width="0dp" or android:layout_height="0dp" is used to optimize the width/height.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer.Further, if we need to place the horizontal divider at say 2/3 of the screen(in which case each layout takes 2/3 ,1/3 space respectively), what should be the required modification?

Comment: @LauraStone you can take Linear Layout as a Parent layout and and two Linear layout as child and give weight as per your requirement.

Comment: @LauraStone you have to use the weight attribute. In your example, you have to set layout_weight="2" for the first view, and "1" for the second. The total will be 3, the first occuping 2/3, and the secod 1/3.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#FF9300"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Text" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
               android:text="Text" />
       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Text" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Text" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#FFFB00"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Text" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Text" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Text" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```